# Run a cron job that prints current time in Ubuntu

Tags: php, time, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I want to run a `php` script in every 2 minutes that prints current time in a file called `data.txt`. For this , I have created a file within `/var/www/test/cronjob.php`:

```
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
$ctime = date('d/m/Y h:i:s A');
fwrite($fp, $ctime);

fclose($fp);
```

This works nicely if I run it in my browser. To execute this file in every 2 minutes, within an interval, I write in crontab
`*/2 * * * * /var/www/html/test/cronjob.php`
But its not writing anything in my data.txt file.
I used [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) tutorial.

Comment: you have to call php to fun that .. `*/2 * * * * php /var/www/html/test/cronjob.php` full path to php may be required (but not usually)

Comment: Means ? I did not get your point. Can you explain  bit @Dagon

Comment: explain? look at the example i gave

Comment: Alternately, you could make your PHP script executable, and put a "shebang" as the first line of the file. Check the [examples on this page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) for something easy to copy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron needs to know how to run your script, so you need to specify it in your cron line:

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test/cronjob.php 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

The `1>> /dev/null 2>&1` will quite cron so that it doesn't saves logs.

You will also need to change the path to the file you want to save. It won't be saved in /var/www/html/test/ as you might be expecting, but in your users home directory, which will be `~/<your username>`. To save in another directory, you will need to provide the full path:

```
$fp = fopen('/var/www/html/test/data.txt', 'w');
```

Also make sure that the user running the cronjob has permissions to write to that folder.